# Why converting iterator to list move iterator to last index

Tags: python, iterator

It seems that converting iter. to list move the iter index to last element, why ?

```
l = iter([1, 2, 3])
x = list(l)
print l.next()
```

Error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       print l.next()
>
> StopIteration

Comment: Because that's what it does. Do you know what an iterator object is?

Comment: Ohh it is !
Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because firstly, you are creating a new object. Secondly an iterator object doesn't have all it's item in memory it generates the item on demand, and once you got to the end there is no way back. That's why they call it one shot iterable. Therefor when you call the `list` on an iterator you are creating new list object by consuming the iterator and preserving its items in a list.

For a better demonstration it does something like following:

```
In [8]: l = iter([1, 2, 3])

In [9]: x = [item for item in l]

In [10]: x
Out[10]: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: ***Thanx !*** @Kasramvd